# css linear gradient inside of option tag of a Dropdownmenu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to have a dropdown menu with the Colorbar inside of the option to select them.
This is my Code so far

http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/895130/

html:

```
<div id="legendtest" style="width:50%;margin-left:50px">
<div id="legendGradient"><span style="opacity:0;">.</span></div></div>
<div style="display: inline">
<form action="#">
<label>Farbskala: <span id="Colormenuspan">test lala</span>
<br/>
<select id="Colormenu"></select>
</label>
</form>
</div>
```

js:

```
var first = [
'rgb(43,131,186)',
'rgb(131,193,171)',
'rgb(215,239,178)',
'rgb(252,169,94)',
'rgb(215,25,28)'
];

var second =
["rgb(255,247,251)",
"rgb(236,231,242)",
"rgb(208,209,230)",
"rgb(166,189,219)",
"rgb(116,169,207)",
"rgb(54,144,192)",
"rgb(5,112,176)",
"rgb(4,90,141)",
"rgb(2,56,88)"];

AllColorRampsName = [ "first","second"]

DrawLegend = function(gradient) {


var gradientCss = '(left';
for (var i = 0; i < gradient.length; ++i) {
gradientCss += ', ' + gradient[i];
}
gradientCss += ')';

$('#legendGradient').css('background', '-webkit-linear-gradient' + gradientCss);
$('#legendGradient').css('background', '-moz-linear-gradient' + gradientCss);
$('#legendGradient').css('background', '-o-linear-gradient' + gradientCss);
$('#legendGradient').css('background', 'linear-gradient' + gradientCss);


 }

function CreateFarbskaladropdown(AllColorRampsName){
 $.each(AllColorRampsName, function(j, item) {
   $("#Colormenu").append('<option data-' + item + '-ival="' + j + '" value="' + item + '"> <div id="dm' + item + '">.</div></option>');

var gradientCss = '(left';
 for (var i = 0; i < eval(item).length; ++i) {
  gradientCss += ', ' + eval(item)[i];
  }
  gradientCss += ')';

  $('#dm' + item).css('background', '-webkit-linear-gradient' + gradientCss);
  $('#dm' + item).css('background', '-moz-linear-gradient' + gradientCss);
  $('#dm' + item).css('background', '-o-linear-gradient' + gradientCss);
  $('#dm' + item).css('background', 'linear-gradient' + gradientCss);
});
}

DrawLegend(first)
DrawLegend(second)
CreateFarbskaladropdown(AllColorRampsName)
```

I am trying to put the same div i create to show the legend colorbar in the html to show up inside of the dropdownmenu so i can choose which of the colorbars to use.
Is it even possible to create a div inside of a dropdown menu option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that option tag permitted content is just "Text, possibly with escaped characters (like é)" (from MDN read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option), so you can't put element nor style it.

What you can do is making div that will act like select, nice example can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp

Good luck!

Comment: Thx for pointing me in the right direction i rewritten my code with the Jquery.selectric plugin and it now works .